How do I associate signs with energies when using the law of conservation of energy?
When I was studying vertical spring systems, I came across this question:
A spring that has a 1.25 kg mass at one end is attached to a fixed support and left to oscillate freely. When oscillating, the maximum extension in the spring is found to be 18.0 cm. The diagrams on the right compare the spring when it is unextended and when it is at a point of maximum extension.

When I attempted to find the maximum velocity of the spring while it is oscillating, I attempted to use the law of conservation of energy:
PE(elastic)[at equilibrium] + PE(Gravity)[at equilibrium] + KE[at equilibrium] = PE(gravity)[at max height]
My question is whether if we need to assign the negative sign to PE(Gravity)[at equilibrium] because the force of gravity is opposite to the displacement vector of the mass as the mass is moving upwards, while gravity is pulling it downwards; therefore, wouldn't gravity be doing negative work? So should I assign it the negative sign?
In addition, is the displacement for gravity different from the displacement for springs? Because as the mass is lowered gravitational potential energy decreases due to the loss of height. However elastic potential energy increases due to the spring’s extension.
In summary, I am getting quite confused when I am associating signs with energy because I need to show if whether a force is doing positive work on an object or if it is doing negative work on an object.
Can someone please clarify my misconceptions?
Credits: Cambridge VCE Physics units 3-4 textbook

Whenever you are dealing with potential energy it is best to define the value of the potential energy at a given position/state.
In this case you could define the zero of gravitational potential energy of the pass as in the left-hand diagram and also make that state (unextended spring) as the zero of the elastic potential energy.
Thus the potential energy of the spring & mass (& Earth) system shown in the left-hand diagram is zero as is the kinetic energy of the mass as it is stationary.
Thus the total mechanical energy is zero.
Suppose that in the right-hand diagram the displacement of the mass and the end of the spring is $2x_0$.
The total mechanical energy of the system is now
$\underbrace{-mg2x_0}_{\text{gpe}} + \underbrace{\frac 12 k(2x_0)^2}_{\text{epe}}$
as the mass is at rest.
As no mechanical energy is lost $0 = -mg2x_0 + \frac 12 k(2x_0)^2$
Again measuring distances from the position of the mass in the left-hand diagram, suppose the zero of gravitation potential energy is changed to position $x_0$ below the mass but the zero of elastic potential energy the same.
The mechanical energy balance equation now becomes $+mgx_0 + 0 = -mgx_0 + \frac 12 k(2x_0)^2$, the same as before.
